# pure virtual method called without active exception - run-time err0r

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, runtime-error, g++4.9

this is a very basic code, after running it, i have this run-time error.

```
class A{
        A(){...
        }

        ~A(){...
            t.detach();
        } 

        start_tread(){
            t=std::thread(&A::back_groud_job, this);
        }

        void back_groud_job(){...}

    }

main///
A a =new A();
a.start_thread()'
////just a skileton
```

this code runs fine under windows vs and ,mingw.
on linux g++  i am having this run-time  error, i read something about a bug, but it was g++4.6, i am using g++4.9...

what do i miss, and how do i fix this?

Comment: Do you also get the runtime error when you replace `t.detach()` with `t.join()` in the destructor `~A`?

Comment: What's the implementation of `A::back_groud_job()`? Does it access any member variables of `A`? (This is not clear from your code snippet.)

Comment: back_ground_job().. it is empty, while(1)...

Comment: ok.. it must be a bug, i must say i am using raspberry pi arm version of the g++.

Comment: If you're using threads, you'll need to compile and link with the `-pthread` flag. Are you doing that ? Also in the general case when you get an error, show us that error.

Comment: if i am having run time error, the compilation phase, was over...